# Importing NULL in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, import, null

[This resource](https://books.google.nl/books?id=rfirBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA282&lpg=PA282&dq=pyqgis%20check%20for%20NULL&source=bl&ots=Jgy3Cw7qTc&sig=zz3e6i-DkNbg9-YxYFWx0Ww3hH4&hl=nl&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwigkqPs2P3PAhVCAxoKHQcmDNoQ6AEIYDAI#v=onepage&q=pyqgis%20check%20for%20NULL&f=false) shows how to use `NULL` values in PyQGIS. Within the Python Colsole the comparison `value == NULL` passes without exception. However, when run from my plugin `NULL` is neither in the global nor the local namespace:

> ```
> NameError: global name 'NULL' is not defined
> ```

The only way to check for `NULL` values seems to be to check for an instance of `QPyNullVariant`:

```py
from PyQt4.QtCore import QPyNullVariant

if isinstance(value, QPyNullVariant):
    pass
```

How do I import `NULL` so I can compare `value == NULL`?

For those wondering why and how `NULL` is different from `None` have a look at [this blog entry](http://planet.qgis.org/planet/tag/%5Bpyqgis/). Essentially historically is wasn't possible to return `None`:

> Turns out by removing QVariant from PyQt it had some impact on methods that expected a NULL QVariant - A QVariant with no value. Passing None didn't work because those methods needed the type information that QVariant holds, even when NULL.

On `None` comparisons it says:

> One way to check if something is Null in Python is to use value is None however this will not work with our NULL type. Overloading the is operator in Python is not supported and there is no way we can support this - trust me I have tried. is is really doing id(object) == id(object) under the hood:

Comment: Have you tried **None** instead ?  https://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [`NULL`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.22/core/NULL.html) class is defined in [`qgis.core`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.22/core/index.html):

```
import qgis.core

if f["SAMPLE"] == qgis.core.NULL:
   ...
```

Normally you should be able to do a normal `is None` check however due to tool we use to generate the Python API it will convert null values on the C++ side (which is what QGIS is written in) to `QPyNullVariant`. We tried to talk the PyQt devs around to making it just return `None` but didn't have much luck.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this was what I was looking for. I also have edited my question to provide more information on the topic.

Comment: Good answer. Minor sidenote `None` is used for invalid attributes (e.g. were not specified in setSubsetOfAttributes) so `NULL` was left there on purpose and the two should not be confused.

Comment: Some more context and info: https://woostuff.wordpress.com/2013/08/31/qgis-2-0-dealing-with-null-values-in-pyqgis/